# Convert Array of String into Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this structure:

```
materials= ["a","b","c"]
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
data= [{material:"a"},{material:"b"},{material:"c"}]
```

Comment: Okay, good luck. be sure to let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try ? You should try to solve the problem yourself and post  question showing how you attempted it and maybe point out what's not working to get an answer which will solve your problem and clear your understanding. (Win/Win :) Happy coding.

Comment: use array map for this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: `materials.map(material => ({material}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
materials.map(a=> ({material: a}))
```

An example:

```js
let materials= ["a","b","c"];
const result = materials.map(a=> ({material: a}))
console.log(result)
```

or even shorter (thanks to [Ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele)):

```
materials.map(material => ({material}));
```

```js
let materials= ["a","b","c"];
const result = materials.map(material => ({material}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `const result = materials.map(material => ({material}));`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to do it with Array.forEach() but I was sure there was a cleaner method, now I finally understand what .map() does!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` method.

```js
var materials= ["a","b","c"]
console.log(materials.map(material => ({material})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach()`:

```js
var materials= ["a","b","c"]

var res = [];
materials.forEach((a) => res.push({material: a}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = materials.map((material)=>{
               return ({"material": material})
             });

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Array.map:

```js
const test = ["a", "b", "c"];

const result = test.map(e => {
    return { material: e };
});

console.log(test);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let materials= ["a","b","c"]
let newObj = materials.map(material => ({material}));
console.log(newObj);
```